# Sharepoint online (365) and XLSM-file as content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, excel, document-set

I have some problems with a content type which is based on a XLSM-file. When I click "New" in a document library and choose this content type, excel pops up and opens the template directly. The file doesn't get copied/created in the library where the content type is used.

The problem does not appear for other content types based on .docx, .xlsx files and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a workaround for this is to use the new Sharepoint look for the library. The content type works as it should in the new SP look, but not on a webpart-page with a library/App.